# SVG not same size across different browsers

Tags: html, css, svg

Making a personal site, and I wanted to use my emblem on the front page as an SVG. I wanted to be able to have it change colors when dark mode is activated. However, the logo is being displayed as different sizes on Firefox vs Chrome. I currently have the logo to take up 90% of the container, which is set up to take up 100% of the viewport. Here's the code:

CSS:

```
.logo {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

svg {
    width: 90%;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="logo">
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
        viewBox="0 0 576 576" style="enable-background:new 0 0 576 576;" xml:space="preserve">
SNIP
      </svg>
    </div>
```

I've included a photo of the result, with Firefox on the left, and Chrome on the right.
Thanks in advance.

[image: SVG resizes incorrectly in Chrome.]

Comment: you are missing the svg viewbox, and no definition for your svg width and height in your css

Comment: Sorry, that was a part I had in the SNIP comment, so it wouldn't be so long.

Comment: Still no defined `width` or  `height`. Once you start omitting those, browsers do some strange things. Start by adding those so the browser knows the relative size. Also, chrome looks like the incorrect one since it is obviously not `width: 90%;` there. However, that _could_ make sense if there is no defined height to your svg.

Comment: besides SVG documents do not have `width` and `height` dimensions, because they are vector images. you need to set the size according to your requirement

Comment: They sure do have width and height dimensions! SVGs aren't magic - they don't render in tenseless space or something. With a defined width and height, the browser knows how to intepret things like aspect ratio, viewports etc... What I presume happened here is that chrome initially rendered it smaller, then stretched it to 100%. It preserves the internal ratio, but chrome doesnt increase the height because its technically still valid. If you add a width and height, it knows the aspect ratio.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you mean. I wasn't sure what you meant by no defined width/height, when I had 100% on there, but then I realized you meant, for example, pixels or rem and not percentage, got it. Thanks!

Comment: Using percentages should be fine. As long as its parent container has an explicit or implicit width.

Comment: What is the meaning of 50% apearing on the upper side of the Chrome image?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your SVG has:

- a `viewBox`
- a `width`

your SVG should display the same in all browsers.

The example that you have posted in your question, works correctly in both Chrome and Firefox.

```css
.logo {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

svg {
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 576 576">
    <circle cx="288" cy="288" r="288" fill="rebeccapurple"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```